# How to remove a word from .txt

Tags: python

i am reading a file .txt, now I wanna remove duplicate words.

```
c = collections.Counter()
with open('DatoSO.txt', 'rt') as f:
        for line in f:
            c.update(line.split())


for palabra,count in c.most_common():
   if count > 1 :
       with open('DatoSO.txt', 'rt') as f:
            Here REMOVE
```

I dont know How remove word from file

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?  Remove any words that are written twice in a row?  If you're doing that, then getting rid of the order of the words, as you are now, isn't going to be very helpful.

Comment: You means you want to index the words and rewrite the result to a new file? If you want to index words use an `OrderedSet()`.

Comment: It would help if you could show an example of an input file and what the output should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove content from a file and have the remaining content shifted down. You can only append, truncate or overwrite.

Your best option is to read the file in to memory, process it in memory and then write it back to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions:

```
import re

...

f = re.sub(r'\w+\s?','',f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use re

```
line.remove(string)
```